# Is there a way to save the time a loop took (in ms) in a datatype while the code is running?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, analytics

I would like to see how many milliseconds one "runthrough" in a loop took and I would like to display it in my application to see how my program performs with many features turned on or off. Is there a way to save the time of each run in a loop in a float for example?

The Program I am using is Visual Studio and the language is C++

```
// e.g.

while(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ADD)){
   // here are the features
   // here is the end of the loop and here the time should be saved
}
```

Comment: Use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() around your loop.

Comment: GetTickCount()？Does this meet your requirements? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount)

Comment: thanks dennis didn't think about that. This will fit my purpose. Thanks for the tip @SuarezZhou-MSFT but not quite what I am looking for.